# python flask no imprime datos de mysql en datatable

Tags: html, python, mysql, flask

El problema es que al momento de imprimir mi lista de usuarios en un datatable no me aparecen las letras en pantalla.
me hace el ingreso de los datos y me genera la cantidad de filas que corresponde pero no muestra nada

Eh aquí la muestra
[image: No muestra los detalles]

este es el código html del datatable

```
<table id="example" class="table table-dark table-hover" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Usuario</th>
            <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
            <th scope="col">Rol</th>
            <th scope="col">Estado</th>
            <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
            <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for user in users %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.fullname }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.roll }}</td>
            <td>
                {% if user.estado_user == 1 %}
                <label for="">Activado</label>
                <div class="form-switch">
                    <input class="form-check-input sombra" type="checkbox" role="switch"
                        id="flexSwitchCheckCheckedDisabled" checked disabled>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
                {% if user.estado_user == 0 %}
                <label for="">Desactivado</label>
                <div class="form-switch">
                    <input class="form-check-input sombra" type="checkbox" role="switch"
                        id="flexSwitchCheckDisabled" disabled>
                </div>
                {% endif %}

            </td>
            <td>{{user.fecha_user}}</td>
            <td>
                <!--EDITAR + abre modal Editar usuario-->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success sombra"
                    style="margin-right: 1rem; margin-bottom: 0.5rem;" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                    data-bs-target="#modal_editar_user" data-toggle="tooltip"
                    data-placement="bottom" title="Editar"><i
                        class="fa-solid fa-file-pen"></i></button>
                <!--ELIMINAR abre modal eliminar usuario-->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger sombra" style="margin-bottom: 0.5rem;"
                    data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal_eliminar_user"
                    data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Eliminar"><i
                        class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

y este es mi codigo de python

```
@app.route('/edit_user')
@login_required
def edit_user():
    roll = session["roll"]
    if roll == "comun":
        return redirect(url_for('logout'))
    else:
        cur = db.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM db_intranet.user')
        lista_user = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        return render_template('panel_admin/edit_user.html', users = lista_user)
```

Por lo que e revisado no encuentro el detalle y no se que podría fallar.
Estoy usando python3, flask, flask-mysqldb, firefox y estoy en un sistema linux ubuntu

Comment: Hola Fabian, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 1):

**Solución**

la solución fue cambiar el nombre por el indice de la columna

en vez de poner

```
<td>{{ user.id }}</td>
<td>{{ user.username }}</td>
<td>{{ user.fullname }}</td>
<td>{{ user.roll }}</td>
```

puse

```
<td>{{ user.0 }}</td>
<td>{{ user.1 }}</td>
<td>{{ user.2 }}</td>
<td>{{ user.3 }}</td>
```